# Need help in converting INSERT\UPDATE to MERGE

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is this a good candidate for a MERGE command?

Must the source data also be another table or can it be variables that are passed?

If it must be a table, is inserting the passed variables into a temp table sane?

Could you help me with the syntax?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ConvertToMerge]
    @GL_DT           date
    ,@SRC_SYS_ID     varchar(60)
    ,@MLR_SRC_SYS_CD char(3)
    ,@TRSRY_FEED_DT  date
    ,@Data           varchar(20)
AS
    BEGIN
        IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT
                           @GL_DT
                       FROM
                           MLR_REBATE_IBOR_INFO_2
                       WHERE
                          [GL_DT] = @GL_DT
                          AND [SRC_SYS_ID]      = @SRC_SYS_ID
                          AND [MLR_SRC_SYS_CD]  = @MLR_SRC_SYS_CD
                          AND [TRSRY_FEED_DT]   = @TRSRY_FEED_DT)
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO [dbo].[MLR_REBATE_IBOR_INFO_2]
                            ([GL_DT],
                             [SRC_SYS_ID],
                             [MLR_SRC_SYS_CD],
                             [TRSRY_FEED_DT],
                             [Data])
                SELECT
                    @GL_DT
                    ,@SRC_SYS_ID
                    ,@MLR_SRC_SYS_CD
                    ,@TRSRY_FEED_DT
                    ,@Data

            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN
                UPDATE [dbo].[MLR_REBATE_IBOR_INFO_2]
                SET    [Data] = @Data
                WHERE  [GL_DT] = @GL_DT
                       AND [SRC_SYS_ID]         = @SRC_SYS_ID
                       AND [MLR_SRC_SYS_CD]     = @MLR_SRC_SYS_CD
                       AND [TRSRY_FEED_DT]      = @TRSRY_FEED_DT
            END
    END

GO
```

Comment: Yes, this is a good candidate for merge. It's the separate transaction issue that MERGE was designed to thwart. You know that the IF NOT EXISTS can return true, but can be false by the time you hit the update, right? Same if you do UPDATE and then insert if @@rowcount = 0, though that approach has always seemed cleaner to me (one less scan = less blocking/locking).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I did it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyMergeTest
     @GL_DT             date
    ,@SRC_SYS_ID        char(20)     
    ,@MLR_SRC_SYS_CD    char(3)
    ,@TRSRY_FEED_DT     date
    ,@Data              varchar(20)
AS
BEGIN

    MERGE MLR_REBATE_IBOR_INFO_2 AS target
    USING 
        (
        SELECT 
             @GL_DT
            ,@SRC_SYS_ID
            ,@MLR_SRC_SYS_CD            
            ,@TRSRY_FEED_DT
            ,@Data
        ) AS source 
        (
             GL_DT
            ,SRC_SYS_ID
            ,MLR_SRC_SYS_CD            
            ,TRSRY_FEED_DT
            ,Data
        )

    ON (
        target.GL_DT            = source.GL_DT              AND
        target.SRC_SYS_ID       = source.SRC_SYS_ID         AND
        target.MLR_SRC_SYS_CD   = source.MLR_SRC_SYS_CD     AND
        target.TRSRY_FEED_DT    = source.TRSRY_FEED_DT 
        )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET Data = source.Data
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   
        INSERT 
            (
            [GL_DT],
            [SRC_SYS_ID],
            [MLR_SRC_SYS_CD],
            [TRSRY_FEED_DT],
            [Data]
            )
        VALUES 
            (
            [GL_DT], --<<it looks like these can eiether be the variable eg, @GL_DT, or prefixed by 'source.'
            [SRC_SYS_ID],
            [MLR_SRC_SYS_CD],
            [TRSRY_FEED_DT],
            [Data]          
            );



END
```